# KeyError: -1 from trying to combine two appended dfs

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to combine two appended CSV files but I keep getting in return a KeyError: -1. I'm not sure why as I have been following a coding tutorial and for him, it works perfectly fine. The two different csv file groups have different formats and so this code will remove the 2 empty columns from one of the formats.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

appended_data = []

for f in glob.glob ('C:\\Users\\xxx\\PycharmProjects\\xxx\\raw\\*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header = None)
    appended_data.append(df)

df = pd.concat(appended_data)

df.rename(columns={0: "volume",
                   1: "weighted volume",
                   2: "open",
                   3: "close",
                   4: "high",
                   5: "low",
                   6: "timestamp",
                   7: "transactions",
                   8: "date"},
          inplace=True)

appended_data_new = []

for f in glob.glob ('C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\PycharmProjects\\xxxxxx\\*.csv'):
    df_new = pd.read_csv(f, header = None)
    appended_data_new.append(df_new)

df_new = pd.concat(appended_data_new)
df_new.dropna(axis=1, inplace = True)

df_new.rename(columns={0: "volume",
                    1: "weighted volume",
                    2: "open",
                    3: "close",
                    4: "high",
                    5: "low",
                    6: "timestamp",
                    7: "transactions",
                    10: "date"},
          inplace=True)

df_final = pd.concat([df, df_new])

path = 'C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\PycharmProjects\\xxxxxx\\check point\\'
path = path + 'cp1-'+ df_final.iloc[-1][-1][0:10] +'.csv'

df_final.to_csv(path, header=True, index=None)
```

The following traceback error occurs:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/xxxxxx/PycharmProjects/xxxxxx/Clean_data.py", line 46, in
> <module>
>     path = 'C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\PycharmProjects\\xxxxxx\\check point\\' + 'cp1-'+ df_final.iloc[-1][-1][0:10] +'.csv'   File
> "C:\Users\xxxxxx\PycharmProjects\xxxxxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
> line 942, in __getitem__
>     return self._get_value(key)   File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\PycharmProjects\xxxxxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
> line 1051, in _get_value
>     loc = self.index.get_loc(label)   File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\PycharmProjects\xxxxxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
> line 3363, in get_loc
>     raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: -1
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image: Format 2]

[image: Format 1]

Comment: Which line is causing the error?  And can you provide an example of the data?

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: @ewong Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dylan/PycharmProjects/TradeBox/Clean_data.py", line 46, in <module>
    path = 'C:\\Users\\dylan\\PycharmProjects\\TradeBox\\check point\\' + 'cp1-'+ df_final.iloc[-1][-1][0:10] +'.csv'
KeyError: -1

Comment: @James I think it is line 46 based on the error it produces

Comment: It would be better if you could link the CSV data, too.

Comment: Include the traceback in your post and not in the comments.

Comment: @ewong CSV and traceback are in the post now, thanks

Comment: @theoctober19th it is now on the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexing into your data frame elements to make the file name is causing the error.  In this line:

```
path = path + 'cp1-'+ df_final.iloc[-1][-1][0:10] +'.csv'
```

To get the last date from your data frame using `iloc`, you need to put both the row index and the column index inside the brackets.

```
df_final.iloc[-1, -1]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I get a different error now which is a FileNotFoundError and it cannot find a file or directory as specified, but I named the path as the location I want the csv saved

Comment: ensure the path exists.   and is writable.